# How to pass data to angular app from setBackgroundMessageHandler() when using Firebase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase in my angular app to send push notification in web.I implemented `messaging.onMessage()` for receiving notification when app is in foreground and `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler()` when app is in background.I receive notification without any problem but i need to update values based on the notification is received.I could do update when using `messaging.onMessage()` but how could we do that when using `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler()`.
Even it will be ok if i can store the received value locally and get it in my app.

I did research on this is many places but i couldn't find any solution.
Can some one help me with this?
Thanks!

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "MY_DB_URL",
    storageBucket: "URL",
    messagingSenderId: "VALID_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
return self.registration.showNotification("Title", {body: 'New notification.',})   
});
```

Answer (score 4):

After searching for days found a Github page that contains a solution for it.

What you can do is get a list of window clients which will return a list of the tabs for your origin and then post a message to each window client. (This code would be in the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()`).

To get list of pages is:

```
const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
type: 'window',
includeUncontrolled: true
})
.then((windowClients) => {
for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
  const windowClient = windowClients[i];
  windowClient.postMessage(data);
}
})
.then(() => {
return registration.showNotification('my notification title');
});
return promiseChain;
```

Then to receive the message in the page, add a listener like so:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
console.log('Received a message from service worker: ', event.data);
});
```

Thanks alot guys who contributed in Github.
For more reference go to

https://web-push-book.firebaseapp.com/chapter-05/04-common-notification-patterns/#message-page-from-a-push-event

Hope it will be helpful for you guys.Ping or comment me if you get any doubts in implementing.

Comment: You have no idea how much time you saved me with this, thank you very much.

Comment: Whoop! Celebrate Good Times... Come on!!! Thank you for this!